# Can't get data to flow correctly in SSIS

Tags: ssis, bids

I'm having some issues getting my data flow to do what I want it to.

I'm using an OLEDB Source that calls a stored procedure that uses a table variable to show me the data that I need to use.
It looks like this:

```
ClientID    TimeStamp            IsStart
pic@psdfj   2013-08-28 14:22:59     1
bsd@fjskk   2013-08-28 14:43:21     1
pic@psdfj   2013-08-28 15:23:01     0
..and so on
```

I need to create two new columns, one with the timestamp, and the other with the IsStart column addded up.  (I'm keeping track of when users are online and capturing the timestamp.)
So I have a currently empty table in my SQL Server db called tblUserUsage, with the columns:

```
tblUserUsage (example of what the data would look like)
TimeStamp           NumberOfUsers
2013-08-28 14:22:59       1
2013-08-28 14:43:21       2
2013-08-28 15:23:01       1
```

I'm having issues getting my data flow to output to those columns.  Right now I have the storedprocedure call connected to a Derived Column, then to a script.  But that isn't working as it's not letting me output to the outputbuffer in the script when I create output columns.  Just for clarification - the script will be in VB.NET

This is what my script looks like so far.  I have a NumberOfUsers column added to the output.  But I still have no Output0buffer
[image: Picture of Code]

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Can you post your script? if its too long at least post the output section. That might give us an idea of whats going on

Comment: I had some basic if statements that would increment the number of hours, but for some reason I have no output buffer?  I'm not sure why as in another part of the SSIS package I have a script and I have an output buffer.  But this one doesn't..I'm essentially just taking the Timestamp and the updated number of users and putting them into a table in a database.

Comment: What kind of script are you creating? (source, transform...) Destination scripts, as I recall, have no output columns.. maybe that's it?

Comment: It's a transformation script.

Comment: It's crazy that it isn't generating an Outputbuffer, because I have a very similar script in another data flow task, and it works just fine!  Even my colleague was completely stumped.

Comment: Im at a loss myself.. Im gonna look around and see if I can find something. The scrip task is usually straight forward; this is puzzling

Comment: take a look below, maybe that'll help

Comment: Is this a synchronous or asynchronous transform? (You only get an OutputBuffer generated in your code for asynchronous transforms; compare the MSDN articles [Creating an Asynchronous Transformation with the Script Component](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136133.aspx) and [Creating a Synchronous Transformation with the Script Component](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136114.aspx).)

Comment: Oh my.  Thank you Edmund, that fixed the problem.  I can't believe it was that simple and so easily overlooked.  Thank you!!  You've made my life so much less stressful.  Thank you as well TsSkTo for trying to help as well.  I really appreciate it.

Comment: @EdmundSchweppe You could probably add that as an answer. It seems like the type of information that would be nice to have documented here on SO.

Comment: @TsSkTo good idea; will do.

Comment: @Nick glad to help. (I've been burned by this sort of thing before myself.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only get an OutputBuffer generated in your code for **asynchronous** transforms (where the `SynchronousInputID` property of one or more outputs is set to zero). For synchronous transforms, your output columns will be in the InputBuffer.

Compare the MSDN articles [Creating an Asynchronous Transformation with the Script Component](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136133.aspx) and [Creating a Synchronous Transformation with the Script Component](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136114.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Did you add a column to your output like this?

[image]

Then your output buffer would look something like this:

> TableOutputBuffer.OutputColumnName = "hello";

Take a look a this sample I found [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136060.aspx) and maybe compare it to your code.. I usually write my scripts in c# so I can tell you if you're missing anything off the top of my head, but it might be worth a try.

```
    Public Class ScriptMain
Inherits UserComponent

Dim connMgr As IDTSConnectionManager100
Dim sqlConn As SqlConnection
Dim sqlReader As SqlDataReader

Public Overrides Sub AcquireConnections(ByVal Transaction As Object)

    connMgr = Me.Connections.MyADONETConnection
    sqlConn = CType(connMgr.AcquireConnection(Nothing), SqlConnection)

End Sub

Public Overrides Sub PreExecute()

    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT AddressID, City, StateProvinceID FROM Person.Address", sqlConn)
    sqlReader = cmd.ExecuteReader

End Sub

Public Overrides Sub CreateNewOutputRows()

    Do While sqlReader.Read
        With MyAddressOutputBuffer
            .AddRow()
            .AddressID = sqlReader.GetInt32(0)
            .City = sqlReader.GetString(1)
        End With
    Loop

End Sub

Public Overrides Sub PostExecute()

    sqlReader.Close()

End Sub

Public Overrides Sub ReleaseConnections()

    connMgr.ReleaseConnection(sqlConn)

End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Yes, I did TsSkTo.  I have added my output column names, but for some reason there is no Outputbuffer generated in my code in the bufferwrapper.  I'm not sure why.  I've recreated my script multiple times, but to no avail.

Comment: To answer your question TsSkTo, in VB it is a little different to the fact that you don't have to use SqlConnection or DataReader (maybe it's how I have the data connection already added onto it in the data flow task), but the code isn't generating the Sub CreateNewOutputRows(), as well as no Output buffer for the columns I created in the output.  I'm completely stumped as I have pretty much the same script in a different data flow in the same package, and it works without any issues at all.  So I'm completely stumped.